# Number formation from given digits

Tags: number-theory

I was asked this question in a recent interview. You are given two digits $0$ and $9$. Using only these two digits you must form the least positive number that is a multiple of a given '$n$' . The value of $n$ will be provided before hand. For example if we are given $n$ as $7$ then the answer will be $9009$ .

I tried using some basic divisibility principles but was not able to come up with a correct solution and code it up. Probably I need some help in number theory

Comment: I suspect this kind of problems are usually purely algorithmic in nature with only a bit of number theory at most.

Comment: similar question in hacker rank https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/codesprint5/challenges/special-multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a recurrence:

Let $f(k,x) \Leftrightarrow \text{There is a number with k digits made of 0s and 9s that is equal to x modulo n}$

Then it is not hard to compute $f(k,x)$ using $\{ f(k-1,y) : y \in [0..n-1] \}$

This algorithm takes $O(cn)$ time where $c$ is the number of digits in the answer. From intuition I would guess that $c$ is generally $O(\log(n))$.

Comment: I didn't understand the recurrence. It would be nice if can please elaborate further

Comment: You add one digit at a time starting from the rightmost. That way you only need to consider whether you add $9 \cdot 10^{k-1}$ to the number or not.

Comment: My immediately preceding comment is bottom-up, which is for an implementation that saves space, but if you want you can think it top-down too: You only need to see what the number without the first digit can be modulo $n$, to figure out what the number with the first digit can be modulo $n$. For that you need to know for all modulos whether it is possible to get it with a number having one digit less, which gives the recurrence.

Comment: Are you pointing towards a dynamic programming bottom up solution ? If so what will be the base cases ?

Comment: Well we have to exclude $0$ and $00$ and so on.. so what do you think a suitable base case would be? Don't forget that with a 2-dimensional recurrence generally we will have a 1-dimensional base case.

Comment: I'm pretty weak at DP . But, one possible case can be when k=0, then we can't form a number

Comment: Okay one way to get used to DP is to actually construct a little table for small values. I'll just give you the base case for this and you can see how it generates the whole table. A number that doesn't have only zeros must have a rightmost nine. So our base cases can be $f(k,9 \cdot 10^{k-1}) = \text{true}$. Notice that for every number if you chop off one digit at a time from the front you will end up with one of the base cases. So at each iteration of $k$ from $1$ to $\infty$ you just add the relevant base case to the "obtainable moduluses", besides whatever comes from the recurrence.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat similar to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643292/number-with-digits-5-and-7) I recently answered.

We want a number $...d_{5}d_{4}d_{3}d_{2}d_{1} \equiv 0 \mod 7$ where the $d_{i}$ are digits restricted to 0 or 9.

Let $b_{i}=0$ if $d_{i}=0, 1$ if $d_{i}=9$.

Then
$$9(...b_{5}b_{4}b_{3}b_{2}b_{1}) \equiv 0 \mod 7$$
$$...b_{5}b_{4}b_{3}b_{2}b_{1} \equiv 0 \mod 7$$

Converting powers of 10 modulo 7 gives:

$$...+4b_{5}+6b_{4}+2b_{3}+3b_{2}+b_{1} \equiv 0 \mod 7$$

The $b_{i}$ are 0 or 1 so the last three terms can not exceed 6, so we can't have a 3 digit solution. With $b_{4} = 1, b_{1} = 1$ we have the smallest solution, which corresponds to 9009.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
public class Solution
{

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            Queue<Long> candidates = new LinkedList<Long>();
            candidates.add((long)9);
            System.out.println(recurrence(candidates,number));

    }
    public static long recurrence(Queue<Long> candidates,int num)
    {
        long candidate = (Long) candidates.poll();
    if(candidate % num == 0)
        return candidate;
    candidates.add(candidate*10);
    candidates.add((candidate*10)+9);
    return recurrence(candidates,num);

   }
}
```

Based on the concept of amplitude search.

Answer (score -1):

Start with $9$. Divide this by $n$ and take the remainder. Call the remainder $R$. If $n$ divides $10R+9$ then add the digit 9 and you are done. If not add the digit $0$ and divide $10 R$ by $n$ and take the remainder. Repeat the process.

The proof of this follows from the observation: If we have a number $X$ and add an extra digit $Y$ then the new number is $10X + Y$ and the new remainder is obtained by dividing $10 R+ Y$.

In your example:

$$
 9 = 1 \times 7 + 2 ~~~ R=2, ~~\text {7 does not divide $2\times 10  +9$}\\
 2\times 10 = 2 \times 7 + 6 ~~ R = 6, ~~\text {7 does not divide $6\times 10 +9$}\\
 6 \times 10 = 8 \times 7 + 4 ~~ R = 4, ~~ \text {7 divides $4\times 10 + 9$}\\
$$
So the answer is $9009$

**Added as after thought**

This is the smallest number of the form $900\cdots 09$. Not sure if there is a simple way to find the answer. For example, if $n$ is 367, then the answer is $9909$ but there is no simple way to find it other than some form of a $\alpha-\beta$ pruning.

Comment: If you're referring to alpha-beta pruning, that won't work at all because there is no evaluation function that favours the solution above other possibilities.

Comment: Well you can use $\alpha-beta$ pruning by doing a search and pruning once a solution has been found. For example, $9909$ is found, one can prune all solutions with more than 4 digits.

Comment: That will take no less time than just doing pure brute-force with iterative deepening. That isn't called alpha-beta search, which is used with move-ordering and a good heuristic to prune away branches.

Comment: you may be right.

Comment: By the way, if you pass in the desired modulus into the recursive search function *and* use memoization, you automatically get the DP. This technique is useful in many cases but you must remember that bottom-up implementations sometimes use much less space if the search tree can be computed in layers and each layer relies only on nearby layers.

Answer (score -1):

Since we need the least multiple (M),  of the given number (N), made of only 0s and 9s, it is simpler to just test all the valid numbers in the ascending order.

Use an integer iterator (i) to generate the series by converting it into binary and replacing all 1s with 9s.

Integer series $(i)$ : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...

After binary conversion $(i)_2$: 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, ...

Parse it into a decimal value.

Multiply with 9 to get valid M candidates:  9, 90, 99, 900, 909, 990, ...

Then test divisibility with the N.

This IS a brute force method but, rules of divisibility can be used to optimize the time. For example, if N = K x $2^n$, or N = K x $5^n$ then we can eliminate all the Ms which are not of the form M = L x$10^n$ , where K and L are some constants.